# Angular 11 table with two nested expandable rows

Tags: angular, html-table, mat-table, angular11

I'm having a hard time implementing a table with two levels of nested expandable rows.
I'm following [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) and I've added a second level of expansion, but it's not working.
[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-hodo1k?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html) you can find my work.
Basically I want to click on row "Street 1, 78542, Kansas" and open it, but I get errors like it's undefined.
Where's the error? I've simply copied the first level of expandable rows to a nested level.

Answer (score 0):

In your `html` here

```
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="innerDisplayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: innerDisplayedColumns;"
                        [class.example-element-row]="row.addresses?.data.length"
                        [class.example-expanded-row]="innerExpandedElement === row" (click)="toggleSecondRow(row)">
                    </tr>
```

It's because `row.addresses.data` is undefined.

You have to update the line 44

```
[class.example-element-row]="row.addresses?.data.length"
```

to

```
[class.example-element-row]="row.addresses?.data?.length"
```

**UPDATE**

In

```
  toggleSecondRow(element: Address) {
    console.log('INNER ELEMENT ', element);
    element.addresses &&
    (element.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data.length
      ? (this.innerExpandedElement =
          this.innerExpandedElement === element ? null : element)
      : null;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

Your object `(element.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data` is undefined. That's why you have the error. You need to put data inside if you want to toggle the nested row.

The `console.log` show us that

```
INNER ELEMENT
addresses: Array[1]
  0: Object
    city: "Kansas"
    street: "Street 1"
    zipCode: "78542"
    __proto__: Object
  city: "Kansas"
  street: "Street 1"
  zipCode: "78542"
__proto__: Object
```

Your `element` has `addresses`. But no the `addresses` has no `data` properties.

Comment: it solved the first row error, but now when I click on the inner row it gives the same error: "
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')". I've updated the url in the question

Comment: but element.addresses is not undefined so I don't get why it can't create the mattabledatasource. I've tried logging element.addresses and it's an array with one object

Comment: I didn't say `element.addresses`  was undefined, I said `(element.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data` was undefined. I've updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried to do  element.addresses = new MatTableDataSource(element.addresses); but it tells me Argument of type 'Address[] | MatTableDataSource<Address>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Address[]'. and I don't understand why. I've updated the method with this assignment to show the error